# Question about usage of Swedish words "som" and "vem"

Tags: cross-linguistic, swedish

In the song "Jorden är ett litet rum," Eva Dahlgren sings "kvinnan som lever sitt liv i Stockholm..." Would it be correct to say "kvinnan *vem* lever sitt liv i Stockholm"? I ask in part because the equivalent in English -- people using *that* in instances when they could use *who* -- drives me nuts. For example, one hears people in the U.S. say things like "man *that* just walked down the street," instead of "man *who* just walked down the street." Would *vem* have been a more accurate, or altogether incorrect, choice?

Comment: Note that in English we use 'that' for restrictive relative clauses and 'which' for non-restrictive (to strengthen the adverbial comma).  Using 'that' instead of 'who[m]' also reinforces the restrictive nature, which may be more important than gender.

Comment: My Swedish is pretty limited, but I don't think I've ever encountered _vem_ used in that way.

Comment: @amI While it is true that in English only *wh-* terms can be used with non-restrictive relatives or following a preposition, the notion that only *that* can be used with restrictive relatives is an arbitrary invention of late-19th-century stylists which has never been universally accepted.

Comment: @StoneyB - exactly! 'That' may not be universally accepted, but it does have a nuance (toward restriction) and that is a good reason to excuse people THAT use it (when referring to people THAT can be identified by a restricting action).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be utterly incorrect to use *vem* in this case. The default pronoun to use as subject or object in a relative clause in Swedish is *som*.<sup>1</sup>

In all the Nordic languages, *vem* ‘who(m)’ is used in three ways:

- *as an interrogative pronoun ‘who(m)?’*
  By far the most common usage; one might say almost the only usage in practical terms.
- *as the object of a preposition*
  Only when immediately following the preposition (‘with whom’, ‘to whom’). Unlike in English, this construction is highly formal and stilted; all the Nordic languages vastly prefer *that… with* (*som… med*) to *with whom* (*med vem*),<sup>2</sup> and this usage must be categorised as reasonably rare, especially in the spoken language.
- *as a pseudo-relative pronoun that includes its own antecedent* (archaic)
  That is, meaning ‘(s)he who/they who’ or ‘whoever’. In this use, the old, otherwise entirely defunct nominative *eho* (Danish and Norwegian *hvo*) is sometimes used, but the whole construction is *exceedingly* rare, archaic, and stilted. The only example I can think of that has any currency at all is the Danish (and Norwegian, I think?) fixed phrase *hvo intet vover, intet vinder* ‘he who dares nothing, wins nothing’ or more idiomatically, ‘nothing ventured, nothing gained’. But this expression doesn’t exist in Swedish at all, and I very much doubt anyone would use *vem* or *eho* in this way in modern Swedish in any context at all.

Note that there is no use at all of *vem* as a simple relative pronoun ‘that/who(m)’ in that list. There are some interrogative pronouns, like *var* ‘where’ and *vilket* ‘which’, that do also function as relative pronouns, but *vem* is not one of them.

It is worth noting that *vilket*, which does function as a simple relative pronoun, is not used like ‘which’ in English: its antecedent is invariably a clause or some type of more or less clearly defined notion, never a simple noun phrase. This is somewhat similar to (but still distinct from) the difference in English between restrictive and non-restrictive usages of *that* and *wh-* words (see StoneyB’s comment above).

This is also why only *vilket* (neuter) is used relatively: the commune *vilken* would not make sense with reference to an abstract notion. In cases where *vilket* is used, the simpler relative pronouns may not be used, just like the corresponding cases in English can only take *which*, never *that*. Or to put it in different terms: cases where English can use either ‘that’ or ‘which’<sup>3</sup> can only take *som* in Swedish, while cases where English ‘that’ would be ungrammatical must take *vilket* in Swedish:

> The necklace **that/which** I bought for her birthday turned out to be a fake, **which** *(*that)* is a shame.
>
> *Halsbandet **som*** (*vilket) *jag köpte till hennes födelsedag, visade sig vara falskt, **vilket*** (*som) *var synd.*

---

*Notes:*

<sup><sup>1</sup> It is perhaps worth noting as an aside that where Swedish and Norwegian have only one relative pronoun, *som*, Danish has two, distinguishing between *der* (lit. ‘there’) used only as a subject, and *som* used as either subject or any other constituent.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> As in English, the default relative pronoun *som* ‘that’ cannot be used directly following a preposition: **med som* ‘*with that’ is as ungrammatical and nonsensical in Swedish as it is in English.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> I am counting the difference between restrictive and non-restrictive as belonging to the same case type here; so even if one may sometimes be preferable to the other because of the level of restriction inherent in the relative clause, they are still nominally interchangeable.</sup>